# javascript splice() odd function

Tags: javascript, splice

I like to do recursive scripts like:

```
var slask="http://www.vskg.se/a-konstnarer/kn_1180/t_bild1.jpg?1357162516228";
slask.split("/").splice(3,50).join("/");
```

to remove `http://www.vskg.se/` and this returns:

```
/a-konstnarer/kn_1180/t_bild1.jpg?1357162516228
```

as I want!
Why is this strange?
because `splice()` is supposed to
delete all items from 3 to 50,
but what it does is
return all items from 3 to 50.
Is this normal, or is it only in Opera, Safari and Chrome in OSX?

Answer (score 4):

`splice` deletes the items from the origial array and returns them.

If you look at `slask` after this code has been run, you will see that it is the "deleted" part.

In fact, you are actually removing the path from the URL and having it returned.

The non-destructive alternative is `slice`.

Also, note that the second argument is optional. You don't have to set it to a high number.

```
slask.split("/").slice(3).join("/");
```

Answer (score 1):

splice both removes and adds items to an array:

```
var leftovers = array.splice(index,howmany,item1,.....,itemX)
```

where index is the starting point
`howmany` is the number to remove (if any)
remaining arguments to inject at the given `index`

`array` now is the result of adding any items from the remaining arguments minus the items removed specified by `howmany`.
`leftovers` is the items you took out by splicing if howmany is greater than zero.

so:

```
var arr = ["one","two","three"];
var removed = arr.splice(1,1,"green");

removed >> ["two"] 
arr >> ["one","green","three"]
```